# I can't drag and drop any element in android studio after update

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

After update the android studio I am enable to use material designing. but I can't user any UI element in drag and drop mode.
mouse curse shows in halfly cutted black circle

[image]

Comment: What version are you running?  What version did you update from?

Comment: version 1.1 to version 1.5

Comment: which operating system?

Comment: windows 10  operating system

Answer (score 4):

It is not very obvious from your screen shot but unless I'm mistaken, you are looking at an `activity_*.xml`. If this is uneditable, I believe you should have a corresponding `content_*.xml` which should look, at Design View, the same as what you are viewing in your screen shot but editable.

Why this happens and what is the difference between the two files, I don't know yet. So far I have experienced this when generating `RelativeLayout`s.

Comment: This does not work. I do not get another xml file. I only get the one "activity_main.xml". How are you getting the "content_*.xml"?

Answer (score 4):

I have found a solution that works for me

go to setting > appearance and behaivor > check drag n drop with ALt press
click apply
again goto same and now uncheck the drag n drop with ALT press click apply. 
**wacky but works**

Comment: Indeed this solution works for me, even on Android Studio 4.1 in 2020/2021 now. A little unbelievable to me that this bug (seems to me) still exists after 4 years.